# How to install ubuntu on lenovo miix 3 10".

Tags: 14.04

When I try to install from usb I get an error 'there is no option to boot from usb.'
 This tablet runs on intel z3700 series

Comment: if i have posted this question in the wrong place please some one guide me

Comment: This is exactly the place. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Look here:
http://www.normalesup.org/~george/comp/linux_lenovo_miix3/

The person is running Debian though. I am also researching this and looking into doing it to a Miix3.

Answer (score 1):

format it in MBR format (GPT does not seem to work, which makes it non-UEFI compliant) with a single FAT32/LBA partition (type 0x0C) and put the bootloader as EFI/boot/bootia32.efi